# Hadoop jobs via C#?

Tags: c#, .net, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I would like to play around with Hadoop, but not much of a Linux guy. Is HDInsight Emulator the only way to use it on Windows? I found a Windows binary Distro of the "real" Hadoop and got that up and running, but it seemed like the Microsoft Map Reduce client couldn't connect to it? I was fine with using the HDInsight Emulator, but it seemed like it was really old and not supported anymore and half the stuff on the UI didn't really work (like browsing for files, looking at jobs, etc).